Azure Event hub check pointing on multiple containers
Is there currently a way to subscribe to the whole storage account (multi-containers)?
I want to checkpoint my event hub consumer to multiple containers or the entire storage account, my use case is that I'm interacting with multiple containers, and events are dispatched through them, for now, what I've read through the documentation and examples is only possible to subscribe to one container.
this is my current implementation where listening to one container, when the metadata changes the event gets picked by the consumer.
sharedCredential, errAzCred := container.NewSharedKeyCredential(ae.AccountName, ae.AccountKey)
    if errAzCred != nil {
        log.WithError(errAzCred).Error("Creating sharedCredential failed")
        return errAzCred
    }
    checkClient, errAzClient := container.NewClientWithSharedKeyCredential(ae.ContanerUrl, sharedCredential, nil)
    if errAzClient != nil {
        log.WithError(errAzClient).Error("Creating container client failed")
        return errAzClient
    }

    checkpointStore, errCheckPt := checkpoints.NewBlobStore(checkClient, nil)
    if errCheckPt != nil {
        log.WithError(errCheckPt).Error("Creating checkpoint store failed")
        return errCheckPt
    }
    consumerClient, errClient := azeventhubs.NewConsumerClientFromConnectionString(ae.HubNamespaceConnectionString, ae.EventHubName, azeventhubs.DefaultConsumerGroup, nil)
    if errClient != nil {
        log.WithError(errClient).Error("Creating event hub consumer failed")
        return errClient
    }
    defer consumerClient.Close(context.TODO())
    processor, errProcessor := azeventhubs.NewProcessor(consumerClient, checkpointStore, nil)
    if errProcessor != nil {
        log.WithError(errProcessor).Error("Creating event hub processor failed")
        return errProcessor
    }

I tried the following, and it worked, but when the metadata of the file changes the event is not picked by the consumer.
properties, err := consumerClient.GetEventHubProperties(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, partitionID := range properties.PartitionIDs {
        log.Debugf("start consuming partition %s", partitionID)
        partitionClient, errPC := consumerClient.NewPartitionClient(partitionID, nil)
        if errPC != nil {
            log.WithError(errPC).Error("couldn't create a partition client")
            return errPC
        }
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if errProcess := ae.ProcessEvents(partitionClient); errProcess != nil {
                log.WithError(errProcess).Error("failed to process the event")
            }
        }()
    }

Thank you

The simple answer is 'no', with what we ship in the SDK.
However, we do provide a customization point if you want to build your own checkpoint store. The interface is pretty simple:
type CheckpointStore interface {
    // ClaimOwnership attempts to claim ownership of the partitions in partitionOwnership and returns
    // the actual partitions that were claimed.
    ClaimOwnership(ctx context.Context, partitionOwnership []Ownership, options *ClaimOwnershipOptions) ([]Ownership, error)

    // ListCheckpoints lists all the available checkpoints.
    ListCheckpoints(ctx context.Context, fullyQualifiedNamespace string, eventHubName string, consumerGroup string, options *ListCheckpointsOptions) ([]Checkpoint, error)

    // ListOwnership lists all ownerships.
    ListOwnership(ctx context.Context, fullyQualifiedNamespace string, eventHubName string, consumerGroup string, options *ListOwnershipOptions) ([]Ownership, error)

    // SetCheckpoint updates a specific checkpoint with a sequence and offset.
    SetCheckpoint(ctx context.Context, checkpoint Checkpoint, options *SetCheckpointOptions) error
}

The implementation we ship with, if you need inspiration, is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/main/sdk/messaging/azeventhubs/checkpoints/blob_store.go

Thank you so much for the hint, I will consider the customized checkpoint store.
